# What html or css attribute should I modify so that a mobile browser shows the website with no blank space on the right?

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser, safari

I am making a website for mobile devices and It will be fixed 480 pixels width but when I view it on my ipod I see a huge blank space on the right. how can I tell the mobile browser with html / css to show it like a mobile page? I tried

body{width:480px}

and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this meta tag to your page: (do not use the maximum-scale=1 part that many popular ones contain. Zooming is required by some people no mater how nice your page is.)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and then you need your mobile layout to be 100% width instead of a fixed width, there are far to many devices with different sizes. Also NEVER check user agent... Ever.

```
body{ width:100% }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your iPod's screen is probably not 480 pixels wide especially while in landscape mode.
Try using percentage on a wrapper div instead of the body so the width will always be filled.

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">content of the site</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper
{
  width:100%;
}
```

You might also want to check the user agent if you want to put mobile specific code.

Comment: "You might also want to check the user agent if you want to put mobile specific code." That is some of the worst advice you can give. It will only lead to more problematic code that does not hold up in time.

Comment: How would you go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Viewport META tag?

Comment: no, now Ive found <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> I'm tring it